# What are the security risks of allowing all characters in the website URL?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, url

I'm using the [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/) PHP framework. In one of the config files, you can set the allowed URL characters:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

So if I attempt to go to this url: *website.com/controller/%22quotedString%22*, I will get an error unless I append a quote to the permitted characters:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] .= '"';
```

My application actually needs to allow *all* weird characters in the URL, but I don't want have a huge hardcoded list of characters. Codeigniter warns against allowing all characters:

> ```
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Allowed URL Characters
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
> | as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
> |
> | Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
> |
> | DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
> |
> */
> ```

They don't say exactly what are security issues with allowing all characters. So what are the issues?

Comment: Smells to me like a poor man's defense against injection... but I don't know, of course.

Comment: CodeIgniter is gifted with hopelessly misguided input filtering features like this. Anyway - there are always going to be some limits on what characters you can put in a URI, because web servers typically disallow some (commonly `%00`, `%2F` and `%5C`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no inherent security risks to allowing all possible characters in your URL.  Security issues depend on what your application does with them.

Comment: You mean something like `exec($parameter1)`?

Comment: Bingo it all depends on whether use of the url allows for unforseen injection of code/data into your app/db that you do not watna nd could be harmful, like if you use `file_get_contents` on a user inputted file path and then `include` that file, @Pwner That could be harmful depending on what `$parameter1` is and whether its been validated or not.

Comment: @Pwner, Exactly.  :-D  But it can be more subtle too.  For instance, I've seen problems on StackOverflow will escape data coming from the user for initial insertion into their database, but will not escape the data if it is used in a secondary query later on.  Second-order injection is very common!  Other problems also exist.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11234/how-does-hacking-work). It pretty much explains what a user can do if you allow them to do whatever they want :) Basically, by not allowing '<' and "'" in your urls, you defend yourself from XSS and SQL Injections. However, if you escape properly and control everything I believe there is no problem in allowing all characters in a URL.

Comment: I don't agree that simply not allowing `<` or `"` in your URLs prevents against XSS and SQL injection.  There are more ways to get data in than via the query string.  Even if there weren't, you must still escape and encode data correctly where needed.  If you do this too early (such as a controller-level URL filtering), you probably are still wide open to problems, and will be causing yourself headaches for other issues later on.

Comment: @Brad, there is always a method to break the code :) This is just a prevention, obviously, more is needed to make the application more secure.

Comment: Fair enough, just clarifying.